# Enabling CORS in .net core Web api and angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

Here I'm using an HTTP POST request from `Angular 6` and it is hitting in the .net core Web API call, but I'm not getting the response output back to `Angular 6` and in console got an error that:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:55654/api/login/auth'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource."

But I'm a bit confused that if it is any `CORS` enabling access issue, it won't hit the web API call. But it hits the API call and I'm not getting the response back.

`Angular 6 HTTP POST` request:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:55654/api/login/auth", credentials, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
 "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
  }).subscribe(response => {
      let token = (<any>response);
      localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
    }, err => {

    });
```

I've enabled the `CORS` in following methods in `.NetCore Web API`

`Configure` Method in `Startup.cs`:

```
...
app.UseCors(options =>
  options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());
 ...
```

`ConfigureServices` Method in `Startup.cs`:

```
...
services.AddCors();
...
```

Comment: Is `app.UseMvc` called before or after `app.UseCors`? It needs to be AFTER `app.UseCors`

Comment: This works....Thank you

Answer (score 6):

On Startup.cs add in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors();
```

On Configure add

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

This solved your problem

Comment: Why would this make a difference considering the OP's code snippet from `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments:

The call to `app.UseMvc` needs to be AFTER `app.UseCors`

```
...
app.UseCors(options =>
  options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseMvc();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add a Proxy to access your Backend.
Just add an proxy-file (proxy.conf.json)  to your root directory.

Serve your App with:  ng s --proxy-config [PathToProxy]

For example:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:55654",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md