# Can't make a cross origin request (CORS)

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have enabled CORS in my ASP.NET MVC API, with this code:

```
        public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsName");
        }
        public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            // Configuration and adding Cross-origin resource sharing
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicyName = "CorsName";
                options.AddPolicy("CorsName", builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .Build();
                });
            });
        }
```

I try to get data from API, opening the localhost:6320/api/users and it works, I get all the data. Now when I try to get data from Angular 7 app, the data is not loaded and there is an error

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:6320/api/users' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource."

Why there is an error when trying to get data from Angular app if I have enabled CORS?

Here is the AppSettings

```
  "AppSettings": {
    "DashboardUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:4200",
    "CorsOrigin": "http://localhost:4200"
  }
```

Startup configuration from Startup.cs

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            HostingEnvironment = env;
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment hEnv)
        {
            InitializeIdentityDbAsync(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
            DiagnosticsStartup.Configure(app, hEnv);
            CorsStartup.Configure(app);
            IdentityStartup.Configure(app, Configuration);
            MVCStartup.Configure(app);
        }
                public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        CorsStartup.ConfigureServices(services, Configuration);
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(o => Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<IAppContext, AppContext>();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddScoped<AuthService>();
            services.AddScoped<UserService>();
            EFStartup.ConfigureServices(services, Configuration);
            IdentityStartup.ConfigureServices(services, HostingEnvironment, Configuration);
            MVCStartup.ConfigureServices(services);
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to authorize all origins? You are calling `WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])` and `AllowAnyOrigin()`.
Also verify your `config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"]` returns the good value.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162910/enabling-cors-in-net-core-web-api-and-angular-6/56163155#56163155

Comment: Please add the full `Startup.Configure` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding origins twice. First, through the `.WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])`, then through `.AllowAnyOrigin()`. If only a specific origin is allowed(which I suppose is true considering your configuration), remove the `.AllowAnyOrigin()` call.

Try with:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsName", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

Check what you're getting from `config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"]`. Do you have a key called `AppSettings`?

Futhermore, it might be(and most probably is) that you're calling `app.UseMvc();` before `app.UseCors();`. Make sure your `Configure` method has the following order:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseCors("CorsName");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but still the same error. Yes, there is AppSettings, I add it to the original post.

Comment: @Janis Did you remove ".Build()" at the end?

Comment: Yes, I removed it, still the same error is displayed.

Comment: @Janis What happens if you use '.AllowAnyOrigin()' instead of '.WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])'? Does it work?

Comment: @Janis Also check the order of you calls to 'app.UseCors()' and 'app.UseMvc()' in 'Configure'. Check my edit in the answer.

Comment: I tried using '.AllowAnyOrigin()' , changing order of calls to UseCors and UseMvc, the same error appears

Comment: @Janis Please, post your final version of the Startup.cs(all the code) in an edit to your question. Either you're doing something wrong, or there is a problem with the hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your startup class:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsName", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

and in the Configure method try this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseCors(builder => {
        builder
        .WithOrigins(config["AppSettings:CorsOrigin"])
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
     });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

If works in this way so you have a problem with the Policy and their assignment to the UseCors method.

Answer (score -1):

you have to enable CORS in front end also.Following is one of the many ways how you can enable CORS in angular .

step 1: Create **proxyconfig.json** file inside main project folder(beside src and node_modules).

step 2:

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target":"url to the server", (eg: "http://45.33.74.207:3000")
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

save it inside **proxyconfig.json** file.

step 3: 
add --proxy-config proxyconfig.json in start inside scripts object

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config  proxyconfig.json"
```

inside package.json file.

step 4:
save and start the project with
 `npm start`

**note: if you start project with (ng serve) it will not work.**

Comment: Why would you configure a proxy when you can directly access the backend configuration?